# How can I read a number in between 2 numbers?

Tags: java

I am fairly new to Java and I am trying to write a small program that asks a user to enter an integer between 0-4. I have written this so far and but it doesn't seem to work! Can anyone tell me where am I wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GameCharSelect {

    public static void main(String[] argh){
        int myChar;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        {
            System.out.print("choose a player: ");
            myChar = in.nextInt();
        }while(myChar>0 && myChar<4);

        System.out.println("--------");
        System.out.println("you chose "+ myChar);

    }

}
```

Now I want the number to be 1,2 or 3 or else it loop until the user input one of these but the program accept any number at the moment. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while condition is wrong.
You are checking if the `char` is larger than 0 *AND* lower than 4, and if it is, it will do the loop again, while what you are after is the oposite.
Change the statement to check if myChar is smaller than 1 *OR* higher than 3.
`myChar < 1 || myChar > 3`

You are also missing a `do` at the beginning of the `do-while`.

Comment: thanks for the help...you are almost right...but the condition should have been (myChar <= 0 || myChar >= 4). but anyways ...i was looking for the way to solve the problem and numbers are not important so vote up and thank you

Comment: No: `myChar <= 0` means less than or equal to zero, `myChar >= 4` means larger than or equal to four. You said in question: `Now I want the number to be 1,2 or 3...`. So 0 and 4 is not supposed to be included. From the specifications you gave, my answer is correct.

Comment: oh yea...thats right...my bad ...lol sorry for that coz after that i had to change the numbers from 0,1, 2,3,4 thats why. anyways ...thanks a lot mate

Comment: Then either Edit your question so that the specification is correct, or mark an answer that is correct instead. The answer that is now marked correct is not correct, if following the specification. The current question and marked answer could confuse people who stumble upon the same problem as you did and find this thread.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a `do` keyword in your loop. Also your conditional should be reversed:

```
public static void main(String[] argh) {
    int myChar;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        System.out.print("choose a player: ");
        myChar = in.nextInt();
    } while (myChar <= 0 || myChar >= 4);

    System.out.println("--------");
    System.out.println("you chose " + myChar);

}
```

Comment: @nomis : yea i noticed the "do" part after i posted my question but the condition was killing me. thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

You haf two problems in your code:

- You are putting the while in a wrong way, you should put a do-while statement or put the while before the {...}.
- You also want to run the loop when you put a wrong number (<1 or >3), not when you put the correct number(between 1 and 3)... So you also need to change the expression.

My code would be something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GameCharSelect {

    public static void main(String[] argh){
        int myChar;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        do{
            System.out.print("choose a player: ");
            myChar = in.nextInt();
        } while(myChar<1 || myChar>3);

        System.out.println("--------");
        System.out.println("you chose "+ myChar);

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your loop should look like

```
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Choose a player: ");
    myChar = in.nextInt();
    if (myChar > 0 && myChar < 4) {
        break; // out of the loop
    }
}
```

That is you only `break;` out of it if the scanned value is either 1, 2, or 3.

---

*@Ali, `while(true)` approach is perfectly fine. In fact, it's far more common to see them than a `do-while()` in actual code running out there. The downvote received is subjective and based on individual coding style preference rather than an indication on the correctness of the answer.*

Comment: Never Endless Loop with break. When you can have a normal abort condition

Comment: @pL4Gu33 Purely a matter of style since `nextInt()` is a blocking call here.

Comment: yeah but i think its a wrong way to do that. Use do .. while is much better because "normal condition" and you must go once through it.

Comment: @pL4Gu33 Your downvote is primarily opinion based. There's nothing wrong with the answer. Define "normal condition" and how does it help your program run any better?

Comment: better readable. And sry  for downvote, yes its an opinion (many books bad smell ;)) but i cant delete it now. Can i delete it when you edit your answer?

Comment: What the books were probably trying to convey was to never use `while(true)` to **keep checking a condition** in a loop, or, you'll put the CPU into overdrive (~100% usage). The good practice is to **block** on an *event* (like object's `wait()/notify()`) or I/O (`nextInt()` here) within the loop. Well, what's that line, "With great power comes great.." Ha ha..